# Express route in different file is accessible using prefix of different file

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I have nodejs server file
***server.js***

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const router = express.Router();
const https = require('https');
const app =  express();

const api1 = require('./apps/routes/api1')( app,router);
const api2 = require('./apps/routes/api2')( app,router);


app.use('/api1', api1);
app.use('/api2', api2);


https.createServer(options, app).listen(3500 , function (err) {
        if (err) {
              console.log(err)
        } else
        {
             console.log("server is running!")
        }
    });
```

now ***api1.js*** file

```
module.exports = function (app, router) {
    router.post("/test",function(res,res){
       res.json({
            data:"done"
       });
    })
    return router;
})
```

now ***api2.js*** file

```
module.exports = function (app, router) {
    router.post("/production",function(res,res){
       res.json({
            data:"done"
       });
    })
    return router;
})
```

Now when i call api

***/api1/test***

then response is

```
{
    data:"done"
}
```

Now when i call api

***/api2/test***

then response is again

```
{
    data:"done"
}
```

my question is since prefix for ***test*** api is ***api1***
so if i call using
***/api2/test***
this should return
***404 not found***

Please help me i am confused here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change api1.js
from:

```
module.exports = function (app, router) {
    router.post("/test",function(res,res){
       res.json({
            data:"done"
       });
    })
    return router;
})
```

to:

```
const router = express.Router();
module.exports = function (app) {
    router.post("/test",function(res,res){
       res.json({
            data:"done"
       });
    })
    return router;
})
```

and similar in api2.js.
You're passing router as reference, it means, if you adding path to the router, it is added everywhere when this router is used.

Comment: Thanks you sir! . That was such a silly implementation from my side.